# dropwizard-guice: Order of Managed objects

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` which implements `Managed`.
I am using 'dropwizard-guice' with `enableAutoConfig` ([Dropwizard Guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice#auto-configuration)) to automatically add bundles and managed objects. But AutoConfig adds the managed objects in random order.

But in my case, I am injecting singleton `Foo` instance to `Bar` and I always want `Foo` to be created and added first and `Foo` to be destroyed after `Bar`. Is there a way to achieve the required ordering ?

Comment: What error are you getting? If `Foo` is injected into `Bar`, then it has to be created first and destroyed second... What behavior are you seeing that makes you think something different is happening?

Comment: I've added log statements in `Foo` and `Bar`'s `start()` and `stop()` override methods and I can see `Bar`'s start() is executed before `Foo`'s `start()`. And other way round for `stop()`

Answer (score 2):

so looking at the code, managed objects are simply added to a list. This means that the order you add them to will be the order they are executed at. Now there might be subtleties that will screw you, so I would not rely on that.

The lifecycle in DW is handled by Jetty. So the functionality that starts/stops your beans lives there.

I would implement a custom solution and since you are using guice this will be fairly straight forward and easy.

1. Add a new managed interface "MyManaged"

This will enable you to have 2 different types of managed. MyManaged can also implement sortable or whatever you need to create an order and that way you will be able to exactly control execution order.

2. Add a new Container "MyManagedContainer"

This one will be responsible for your MyManaged classes. It must implement Managed and will be handled by DW. So basically you wrap your own managed objects into a Managed object, so that you have control over what to do.

In MyManagedContainer, in the start/stop you simply delagate to your own start/stop objects.

3. Create everything in Guice.

Guice offers you MultiBindings: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

So, you create your Foo and Bar, they both implement MyManaged and some sort of ordering.

You bind them and inject them as Set into MyManagedContainer. MyManagedContainer you add to the Managed lifecycle of dropwizard.

Tada, you now have exactly controlled execution order.

I apologise for the lack of code, but I have not in fact implemented this. I also use guicey (which has internal support for multibindings and much much more) instead of guice.

Let me know if you need more help with this.

Thanks,
Artur